# Unwanted HTML element flickering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was working on a quick pen for a project when I ran into flickering issues when dragging an element across an image I'm using. Not really sure whats going on here, the problem doesn't seem to occur when you initially load the pen and pan over it the first time, but after that it starts bugging out.

[Link to Pen.](https://codepen.io/JFarenci/pen/bLjOZZ)

Snippet Demo:

```js
$(document).bind('mousemove', function(e){
    $('.tagger').css({
       left:  e.pageX - 55,
       top:   e.pageY - 55
    });
});

$('#crowd').hover(function(){
  $('.tagger').show();
});

$('#crowd').mouseleave(function(){
  $('.tagging').attr('class', 'tagger');
  $('.tagger').hide();
});

$('#crowd').click(function(){
  $('.tagging').attr('class', 'tagger');
});

$('.tagger').click(function(){
  $('.tagger').attr('class', 'tagging');  
});

$(document).on('click', '.tagging li', function(){
  alert($(event.target).text());
});
```

```css
.tagger {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
}

.tagger .frame {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
}

.tagger .name {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  background-color: white;
}

.tagger .name ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}







.tagging {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
}

.tagging .frame {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
}

.tagging .name {
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  background-color: white;
}

.tagging .name ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img id="crowd" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/viking_education/web_development/web_app_eng/photo_tagging_small.png" height="600">
</div>
  
<div class="tagger">
  <div class="frame"></div>
  
  <div class="name">
    <ul>
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
      <li>Fork</li>
      <li>Fyve</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

```
$(document).bind('mousemove', function(e){
    $('.tagger').css({
       left:  e.pageX - 55,
       top:   e.pageY - 55
    });
});

$('#crowd').hover(function(){
  $('.tagger').show();
});

$('#crowd').mouseleave(function(){
  $('.tagging').attr('class', 'tagger');
  $('.tagger').hide();
});

$('#crowd').click(function(){
  $('.tagging').attr('class', 'tagger');
});

$('.tagger').click(function(){
  $('.tagger').attr('class', 'tagging');  
});

$(document).on('click', '.tagging li', function(){
  alert($(event.target).text());
});
```

Comment: you have a loop of hide/show ... but not able to well explain it :)

Comment: comment out $('.tagger').hide(); from mouseleave event

Answer (score 3):

The hover effect consider the cursor and actually your are moving an element with the cursor so what's happening is this:

1. You start inside the `.tagger` element and everything is ok as the cursor is on the `.tagger` element. No event on the `#crowd` as the cursor never touched/hovered the `#crowd` **until now**.
2. Once you click or you do something that bring the cursor on `#crowd` you trigger the **hover** effect which mean that if you leave you will trigger the **mouseleave!**
3. So you hover again on the element `.tagger` and you trigger the **mouseleave** as expected.
4. The element disappear (because of what written in the handler of mouseleave) and the cursor is now on `#crowd` and you trigger again the **hover!**
5. The element `.tagger` appear again, the cursor is on it and you trigger the **mouseleave** of `#croud` and so on ...

The flicker is the infinite sequence (4) (5) (4) (5) (4) ...

---

To fix this you may change the logic as follow. No need to apply the hide/show function, you can simply wrap the image and `.tagger` element inside the same wrapper and apply `overflow:hidden` then keep only the click events.

Here is the full code *(I made the image smaller so we can see it in the reduced snippet)*

```js
$(document).bind('mousemove', function(e){
    $('.tagger').css({
       left:  e.pageX - 55,
       top:   e.pageY - 55
    });
});


$('#crowd').hover(function(){
  $('.tagging').attr('class', 'tagger');
});

$('.tagger').click(function(){
  $('.tagger').attr('class', 'tagging');  
});

$(document).on('click', '.tagging li', function(){
  alert($(event.target).text());
});
```

```css
.tagger {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
}

.tagger .frame {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
}

.tagger .name {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  background-color: white;
}

.tagger .name ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}







.tagging {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
}

.tagging .frame {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
}

.tagging .name {
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  background-color: white;
}

.tagging .name ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container {
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <img id="crowd" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/viking_education/web_development/web_app_eng/photo_tagging_small.png" width='400' height="300">
  
<div class="tagger">
  <div class="frame"></div>
  
  <div class="name">
    <ul>
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
      <li>Fork</li>
      <li>Fyve</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You continuously `hide()` and `show()` `.tagger` repeatedly. `mouseleave` hides and `:hover` shows.

there are two ways to fix this:

1. move the mouseover effect inside the `#crowd` `.hover()`

   - this makes the movement a bit shuddery
   - see this Pen [enter link description here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eVjaWg)
2. delete the `.delete()` call within the  `.mouseleave` handler

Also, a note: The jQuery `.hover()` method takes two callbacks:
   1. for the `mouseenter`
   2. for the `mouseleave`

So the code could be changed a bit in that regard too.

Comment: Because the listener on the document sets the event target to the .tagger box as Clayton points out, then the `.hover` method moves it back again - hence the loopy effect you recognized.

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming .tagger is JUST the border you've drawn. In actuality, there is an invisible box there. The invisible box is on top of #crowd. When .tagger loads, you are no longer hovering over #crowd, you are hovering over .tagger, which is hovering over #crowd.

To fix it, you may change .tagger from one large box around the mouse, to 4 skinny boxes, so that there is nothing directly below the mouse.